# Django Connection Error(Oracle 11g Database)

Tags: python, django, oracle11g, migrate, manage.py

When my Django program connected to Oracle 11g DB, an error occurred.
 When I input “python manage.py migrate” command, a below error occurred.
 (When my Django connected to sqlite3 DB, no problem.)

```
 Django 1.11.22
 cx-Oracle 7.2.2
 python 3.6
 Oracle 11g

(venv) PS D:\python\TEST\ijmes> python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

> **Error Message**. (venv) PS D:\python\TEST\ijmes> python manage.py
>   migrate  Operations to perform:  Apply all migrations: admin, auth,
>   contenttypes, db, sessions  Running migrations:  Applying
>   contenttypes.0001_initial…Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   “manage.py”, line 22, in   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_init_.py”,
>   line 364, in execute_from_command_line  utility.execute()  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_init_.py”,
>   line 356, in execute 
>   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py”,
>   line 283, in run_from_argv  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py”,
>   line 330, in execute  output = self.handle(*args, **options)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py”,
>   line 204, in handle  fake_initial=fake_initial,  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py”,
>   line 115, in migrate  state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan,
>   full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py”,
>   line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards  state =
>   self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake,
>   fake_initial=fake_initial)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py”,
>   line 250, in apply_migration 
>   self.recorder.record_applied(migration.app_label, migration.name) 
>   File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py”,
>   line 73, in record_applied  self.migration_qs.create(app=app,
>   name=name)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py”,
>   line 394, in create  obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py”, line
>   808, in save  force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) 
>   File “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py”,
>   line 838, in save_base  updated = self._save_table(raw, cls,
>   force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py”, line
>   924, in _save_table  result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager,
>   using, fields, update_pk, raw)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py”, line
>   963, in _do_insert  using=using, raw=raw)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py”,
>   line 85, in manager_method  return getattr(self.get_queryset(),
>   name)(*args, **kwargs)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py”,
>   line 1079, in _insert  return
>   query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py”,
>   line 1119, in execute_sql  return
>   self.connection.ops.fetch_returned_insert_id(cursor)  File
>   “D:\python\TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\operations.py”,
>   line 245, in fetch_returned_insert_id  return
>   int(cursor._insert_id_var.getvalue())
>
> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
>   number, not 'list’

Comment: [Django issue tracker](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29938#comment:3) says that v1.11 supports cx_Oracle < 7. It is a closed issue and wont be fixed. I suggest that you downgrade cx_Oracle.